# vector type function implemetation

Tags: c++

```
class City
{
    private:
        int id;
        string name;
        int populations;
        int nooftourist;
        vector<Attraction*>&attractions;
    public:
        City(int id,string name,int populations,int nooftourist):id(id),name(name),populations(populations),nooftourist(nooftourist){}
        void setId(int _id);
        void setName(string _name);
        int getId();
        string getName();
        void display() {}
        vector<Attraction*>getAttractions() { return attractions;}
};

int main(){ 
    vector<City*>cities;
    cities.push_back(new City(111,"Kuala Lumpur",80000,4000));
    cities.push_back(new City(112,"Malacca City",30000,1500)); 
    cities.push_back(new City(113,"Ipoh",70000,3500)); 
    for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++) { cout<<i+1<<"."<<cities[i]->getName()<<endl; } 
    for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++) { delete cities[i]; } 
    vector<Attraction*> att = cities.getAttractions(); 
    att.push_back(new   Attraction(11,"Pavillion",1));
}
```

this is just a part segment from my code,i still have some classes but that is not related to the problem here,when i compile why it said city don't have member `getAttraction`? that is the major problem

Comment: What don't you understand?  This is just part of a class declaration - what isn't working?  Perhaps read up on stl vector?
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: What goes wrong actually? Can you elaborate in your question please?

Comment: int main(){
    vector<City*>cities;
    cities.push_back(new City(111,"Kuala Lumpur",80000,4000));
    cities.push_back(new City(112,"Malacca City",30000,1500));
    cities.push_back(new City(113,"Ipoh",70000,3500));

    for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<i+1<<"."<<cities[i]->getName()<<endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++)
    {
        delete cities[i];
    }

    vector<Attraction*> att = cities.getAttractions();
    att.push_back(new Attraction(11,"Pavillion",1));

}
this is my main function here,got some error while compiling

Comment: My crystal ball tells me it is that you have a reference to a vector that you never initialize in the constructor.

Comment: but your answer dont answer my question

Comment: @MiKe Please post the code in the original question, not as a comment.

Comment: @MiKe Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34562551/edit) your question, instead of providing such additional information in comments. It's not well readable as you can see.

Comment: @MiKe Nathan is right, you either need to omit the `&` from `vector<Attraction*>&attractions;` or initialise the reference correctly in an appropriate constructor.

Comment: @MiKe Why do you need a reference as a member?  Also, why not `std::vector<City>` instead of `std::vector<City*>`?

Comment: so what is my major problem?

Comment: @MiKe The major problem is using references and pointers when they are not necessary, and leaving garbage pointers in your `cities` vector.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is

```
vector<Attraction*>&attractions;
```

Is a reference to a vector and as such you need to initialize it in your constructor.  Since you do not do this your code will fail to compile as references must be initialized unlike pointers.  I don't think you meant to have a reference and by the looks of your code it does not look like need it.  You can simply change it to:

```
vector<Attraction*> attractions;
```

And it should compile.

On a side note I think you meant to have `getAttractions()` to return a reference to the vector so you can modify the vector that the class holds.  If that is the case then change

```
vector<Attraction*>getAttractions() { return attractions;}
```

to

```
vector<Attraction*>& getAttractions() { return attractions;}
```

and

```
vector<Attraction*> att = cities.getAttractions();
```

to

```
vector<Attraction*>& att = cities.getAttractions();
```

I am also unclear on why you are using pointers at all.  In the code you have presented there is no reason to be using them but instead just use regular automatic objects.

Comment: C:\Users\MICHAEL\Desktop\OOPNEW.CPP||In constructor 'City::City(int, std::string, int, int)':|
C:\Users\MICHAEL\Desktop\OOPNEW.CPP|100|error: uninitialized reference member 'City::attractions' [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\MICHAEL\Desktop\OOPNEW.CPP||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\MICHAEL\Desktop\OOPNEW.CPP|193|error: 'class std::vector<City*>' has no member named 'getAttractions'|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: now i dont have & in my class and in the main function,why still dont get it?

Comment: nathan can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from expressions like this one:

`vector<Attraction*>&attractions;` which is a reference to a vector and must be initialized (unlike pointers). You will need to initialize it in your constructor.

It seems you don't really need to use a reference and so changing the above statement to `vector<Attraction*> attractions;` should make the program compile.

However, instead of using pointers I would recommend using regular objects, since you don't really need pointers in your code.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?